# "Rebind" or page_load a usercontrol on a page when a property of the usercontrol is changed in the parent page

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax, event-handling, user-controls

i have a usercontrol.. and i'd like to set one of it's property's from the parent page and at the same time "reload" the usercontrol so it's updated.

formally the usercontrol was picking up a querystring parameter and setting itself up with the querystring parameter.. now i'd like to set this from within the parent page..

open to any suggestions. thanks!

Comment: Expose public methods in the UserControl and call them from the parent page?

Comment: yes this could work.. in my case loading the control dynamically and setting a public property (an id in this case) worked great.